# IOS 8 blocked my phone

Tags: ios

I just downloaded IOS 8. When I turned my phone on and completed the setup it just restarted the setup process and went back to the screen that says hola. I've tried everything and just can't seem to get my phone to complete the setup process. Right now my phone is useless

No error came up, it just went back the the begginging slide

Comment: Could you expand on ***why*** you can't complete the process? What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Phones can and do crash and need help from iTunes to be restored even if no software change has happened. The most common cause of a failure to update was that the phone was already missing a system file and the update just was the "messenger" that checked that file for the first time in a long time.

Why not connect it to a computer with iTunes and then restore the OS to clear out any errors? That will rapidly determine if your problem is a temporary software issue or a deeper hardware problem:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1414 - **Use iTunes to restore your iOS device to factory settings**